# Google Chrome session lost after crashing my computer

Tags: google-chrome

I had several tabs in an incognito window open with flash videos playing in some. I pressed `^W` a few times in rapid succession and my mac crashed (press any key or wait some seconds to restart). When I booted up, Chrome didn't offer to restore my session and `CMD+SHIFT+T` did nothing. How can I get my windows back?

Comment: "Incognito mode opens a new window where you can browse the Internet **without Chrome saving the sites you visit**." [Incognito Mode - Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)

Comment: Chrome does not save incognito sessions, so any recover of said session, will be tough since there is nothing to recover.  If you want Chrome to save your session don't use incognito mode.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Closing the incognito tabs caused the crash. But there were several other normal windows with several tabs each.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is unequivocally: 
No, sorry, you cannot restore those windows in Chrome. This is a feature, not bug, of Incognito Mode.

[How Incognito Mode in Chrome Works](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464)

But if the **content** of the Windows/Tabs is what you're looking for, and not the tabs themselves, you still have a few options.

**1. Browser Extensions.**
You might have a browser extension running in Chrome which saved the data in some format, even though you were browsing Incognito.

To check for such browser extensions, in a new tab navigate to

chrome://extensions/

Look to see if any of the extensions you may have installed have the box "Allow in Incognito" checked.  [Here is what that would look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex7aF.jpg)

Some popular extensions such as TabsOutliner and OneTab will save your pages in Incognito Mode, if configured to do so.  Other extensions may as well, but without knowing which extensions you have installed I cannot give advice.

**2.  Flash History**

You mentioned having Flash videos running before the crash.  Flash will often save files to your hard disk in the form of "Local Shared Objects" or "LSOs"

In OSX you can usually browse for such files in one of these locations:

```
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/

~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

But be careful to avoid making changes when navigating through hidden or protected folders on your system, such as ~/Library/# unless you know what you are doing.

Finally, I don't have enough reputation points to include these links, but they might be useful in your search:

```
 - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en

 - http://www.one-tab.com

 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object
```

Comment: Maybe an edit is in order. I want the non-incognito windows of the session. I was in the act of intentionally closing the incognito ones.